# Chrome Packaged App - Set Custom User Agent

Tags: google-chrome-app, user-agent

I have a published hybrid app that is available on IOS, Android and in what is left of the Chrome Web Store. The Chrome version is also the basis for the MacOS and Windows versions, built using NWJS.

In developing some new functionality for this app, I came across the need to customise the user agent header in direct XMLHttpRequest's from the client code to a third party site. I thought this would be easy, all I wanted to do was to add the app name to the end of the existing navigator.userAgent.

I could not have been more wrong. This results in a refusal to set unsafe headers. Given that using the Chrome debugger you can set any user agent you want, this seems very strange to me.

For IOS I found that I could put some Objective C code in the IOS Wrapper as follows :

```
// get original UserAgent string by using temporal UIWebView
UIWebView *tmp = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *originalUA = [tmp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];

// create custom UserAgent string
NSString *customUA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", originalUA, @" WebViewApp myAppName/myAppVersion"]; 

// set custom UserAgent as default
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:customUA , @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

and for Android some Java code in the wrapper, along the lines of :

```
string ua = webview.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua+" WebViewApp myAppName/myAppVersion");
```

and both of these approaches work fine.

I thought that I could use the chrome webRequest API to achieve the same in the Chrome app by changing the actual XHR headers each time, rather than the simpler approach used in IOS and Android, but I found that this API is only available to chrome extensions and not to chrome packaged apps.

Someone else asked a similar question here a few years ago, but it was never answered. Has anyone now got any suggestions on how to change the user agent for all XHR requests from inside a Chrome Packaged App, or do I need to channel these requests through a server. 
Thinking outside the box, could I attach the Chrome debugger programatically, use that to set the user agent and then detach. I would be loath to leave the debugger attached from a security angle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Apps can use webview so you can use [setUserAgentOverride](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride) and make requests from inside.

Comment: Thanks very much. I found this API but I could not work out where to put the code. Is in it the background page or in the client page? Have you a link to an example? All I can find when googling it is Network.setUserAgentOverride but what is Network?

Comment: I am not sure that I can use a webview in place of the standard window. By default, webviews are prevented from loading any resources packaged with the app and that is the whole basis of a hybrid app, to load the packaged resources. I am not sure I could manage the complexities of communicating between the standard window in which the code runs and a separate web view, in particular dealing with large volumes of data returned to the XHRs.

Comment: Can I use chrome.sockets.tcp.xhr in the client page?

Comment: Regarding webview, all the info and examples are in the documentation I've linked. Webview can also use data:// URLs. As for the sockets API, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go if it can load data URL's. If it can do this sockets will not be necessary.